# Return specific column differences between two tables in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, submissions and updates.  Every time a submission is updated the old values are saved in the updates table and the new values are written to the submission.  What I need is a query that takes a date range, usually the previous month, and returns the submission_id, the name of the column(s) that have changed and the new and old values for the column(s).  How would I go about this?

I basically need to create a report that looks like this:

```
ID    Name     Field Updated     Old Value   New Value
1123  Jim Bob  policyno          515-231     515-321
               zip               77070       77077
1157  John Doe address           123 Main St 122 Main St

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[submissions](
    [submission_id] [int] IDENTITY(100000,1) NOT NULL,
    [policyno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [loanno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [banker] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [effdate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [name2] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [address2] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [city] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [state] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [zip] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [county] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LastUpdatedBy] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[LastUpdatedDate] [smalldatetime] NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[updates](
    [updates_id] [int] IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL,
    [submission_id] [int] NULL,
    [policyno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [loanno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [banker] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [effdate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [name2] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [address2] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [city] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [state] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [zip] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [county] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LastUpdatedBy] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[LastUpdatedDate] [smalldatetime] NULL)
```

Comment: You join the two tables together by submission_id using a long list of `WHERE isnull(name,-1) <> isnull(name,-1) AND ...`.  What did you try before that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I used SQL to write SQL.  By executing this statement:

```
select 
'select n.updates_id as ID, 
n.submission_id as SubmissionID, 
n.Name as name, 
'''+sc.name+''' as [Field Updated], 
convert(varchar(max), o.'+sc.name+') as [Old Value],
convert(varchar(max), n.'+sc.name+') as [New Value] 
from orderedUpdates o 
inner join orderedUpdates n 
on o.submission_id = n.submission_id
and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1
where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())
and  (o.'+sc.name+' <> n.'+sc.name+' OR o.'+sc.name+' is null and n.'+sc.name+' is not null OR o.'+sc.name+' is not null and n.'+sc.name+' is null)  UNION '  
from sysobjects so inner join syscolumns sc 
on so.id = sc.id
where so.name = 'updates'
```

I was able to generate a UNION statement for each column on the Updates table.  Then pairing down that list and combining it with a CTE yields this:

```
with orderedUpdates(rowId,updates_id,submission_id,policyno,
loanno,
banker,
effdate,
name,
name2,
address,
address2,
city,
state,
zip,
county)
as
(
    select Rank() over(partition by submission_id order by updates_id), updates_id, submission_id,policyno,
        loanno,
        banker,
        effdate,
        name,
        name2,
        address,
        address2,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        county
    from updates

)
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'policyno' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.policyno) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.policyno) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.policyno <> n.policyno OR o.policyno is null and n.policyno is not null OR o.policyno is not null and n.policyno is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'loanno' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.loanno) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.loanno) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.loanno <> n.loanno OR o.loanno is null and n.loanno is not null OR o.loanno is not null and n.loanno is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'banker' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.banker) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.banker) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.banker <> n.banker OR o.banker is null and n.banker is not null OR o.banker is not null and n.banker is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'effdate' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.effdate) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.effdate) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.effdate <> n.effdate OR o.effdate is null and n.effdate is not null OR o.effdate is not null and n.effdate is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'name' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.name) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.name) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.name <> n.name OR o.name is null and n.name is not null OR o.name is not null and n.name is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'name2' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.name2) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.name2) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.name2 <> n.name2 OR o.name2 is null and n.name2 is not null OR o.name2 is not null and n.name2 is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'address' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.address) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.address) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.address <> n.address OR o.address is null and n.address is not null OR o.address is not null and n.address is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'address2' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.address2) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.address2) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.address2 <> n.address2 OR o.address2 is null and n.address2 is not null OR o.address2 is not null and n.address2 is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'city' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.city) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.city) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.city <> n.city OR o.city is null and n.city is not null OR o.city is not null and n.city is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'state' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.state) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.state) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.state <> n.state OR o.state is null and n.state is not null OR o.state is not null and n.state is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'zip' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.zip) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.zip) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.zip <> n.zip OR o.zip is null and n.zip is not null OR o.zip is not null and n.zip is null)  UNION 
select n.updates_id as ID,   n.submission_id as SubmissionID,   n.Name as name,   'county' as [Field Updated],   convert(varchar(max), o.county) as [Old Value],  convert(varchar(max), n.county) as [New Value]   from orderedUpdates o   inner join orderedUpdates n   on o.submission_id = n.submission_id  and o.rowId = n.rowId + 1  where n.effDate > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())  and  (o.county <> n.county OR o.county is null and n.county is not null OR o.county is not null and n.county is null )
order by 1,2
```

Comment: The author can just join the two tables together with many `WHERE` clauses.  No need to build a query in memory with CTE or a lot of UNION'ed statements (which would require doing the whole query and getting DISTINCT).  The author needs to have a go at it first and then post what they tried.

Comment: Joining the tables together once will not satisfy the OPs problem.  They want to have different rows for EACH change.  If we only join the table once we won't be able to have a row for more than 1 field that changed.  Please remove your downvote.

Comment: Just join the dbo.[updates] to dbo.[submissions] instead of the other way around.  Or cross join.  Either would eliminate the need for the CTE.

Comment: But there are many updates during the month.  Name went from "1stName" to "2ndName" to "3rdName" and each change would need to be captured showing the old and new value.  How can your hypothetical solution solve that problem?  And the CTE just helps with readablitily.  You could just as easily include it as a derived table if you prefer.

Comment: Eh, I didn't realize what the OP was asking.  You should still switch your non-standard comparison operators to `<>`, wrap the field names in `ISNULL(,-1)`, and don't `ORDER BY` nor `UNION` (`UNION ALL`) unless it's explicitly required.  Sorry, the schema is wrong for the task at hand and I assumed they wanted something else.  There should be, at a minimum, a persisted/computed field for storing the different field name, and a incremented value for one `submission_id`.  But dbo.[updates] should be taller and skinnier, too.  The author looks like they're answering homework without trying.

Comment: Agreed on the isnull.  Disagree on the ORDER BY, the consumer of this data would want to see changes through time.  Disagree STRONGLY on the UNION, we have to have it to get ALL the changes to ALL the fields.  And <> versus != is nitpicking to me, but whatever.

Comment: If you edit the answer, I can change the downvote.  Otherwise it blocks me.

Comment: Done.  I couldn't use the ISNULL solution, because I didn't know what the original datatype was.  Replacing a datetime with -1 would throw.  So I just checked for mismatched null values.  I think we care more about this question than the OP.